# Can a Spring profile be referenced by any of multiple names?

Tags: spring

I am working on a Selenium framework in Java, using Spring. Can a Spring profile be referenced by any of multiple names?   Is this valid code, because it seems to work but I couldn't find any documentation on the `@Profile` annotation that reveals the truth.  Does this really work like an 'alias' mechanism? Anyone know where I can get this information?

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ "ie", "iexplore", "internetExplorer" })
public class IEx64 {
    ...
```

And this is referenced in my framework by executing tests with this parameter:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=iexplore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html):

> Indicates that a component is eligible for registration when **one or
>   more** specified profiles are active

Emphasis added.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think this is valid. see [captain debugs blog](http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/08/using-spring-profiles-and-java.html#.VczsbXFVgt0)

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for something like that.